# Reset all programs to use same audio output

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

Background: So through some messing around or some sort that I've done with my audio, I've found that some programs are set to use my built-in audio, and others are set to use my sound card.  While I know I can manually change each program, when it's playing audio, which output device it's using in pavucontrol, this can be kind of tedious.

Question: Is there a way to automatically set all programs, whether they're currently playing sound or not, to use a single output device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uder defined settings for what application outputs on which sound device are stored in a hidden directory `~/.pulse` in the user's HOME. To restore to default settings we simply remove this directory, e.g. by running the following in a terminal:

```
mv ~/.pulse ~/.pulse.old
```

After restarting the pulseaudio server (reboot, log-out or running `pulseaudio -k`) the per user settings will be resored to defaults.

In case you tinkered with system-wide settings these will still be as you had defined them, you should then be able to restore to defaults by reverting the steps you had taken, or restoring from your backup-files.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work. Is there a way to quickly switch the output device, like if I want to use my speakers, switch all to use sound card?  Or should I make that a separate question?