# I want to split sound

Tags: sound, games, skype, system, split

I would like to split sound between skype and games/music/system.
I want skype to use headphones plugged in, and system to use speakers.
Is that possible?
Microphone - mic in PINK
Headphones - audio on GREEN
Speakers - line in BLUE

Comment: I don't think it is possible without two (or more) sound-cards.

Comment: Related: [How can I specify which programs play sound through headphones and which ones play through speakers?](http://askubuntu.com/q/296950/22949) (answer says it can be done with `pavucontrol`) [Reset all programs to use same audio output](http://askubuntu.com/q/233913/22949) (suggests strongly that it can be done, since someone is trying to undo it)

Comment: The Windows Verion can do this easily in the option menu. Wy the linux versin should not have tzhis feature.

Comment: Exactly my problem, I want to split skype and spotify. Like it is done on my windows PC.

Answer (score 2):

#### PulseAudio libraries

If someone need to handle PA adequately seems to Windows controls they can try their programming skills to maintain their own GUI library to routing PulseAudio. I think it is a rare people.

Though some chances to satisfy some needs always exist. Lookalike `padevchooser` or `paman` and other libraries for PA handling by [Lennart Poettering](http://0pointer.de/lennart/):

[image: PulseAudio Device Chooser 0.9.3]
[PulseAudio Device Chooser 0.9.3](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/padevchooser/)

[image: PulseAudio Manager 0.9.4]
[PulseAudio Manager 0.9.4](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/paman/)

Shortly the PulseAudio is a deep integrated audio server and the way how the users will be route their workarounds still leave is a most important task of sound programmer.

#### JACK libraries

Though exists absolutely different for PA solution despite the many words against this method — it is a JACK integrated to PA libraries.
Lookalike [QjackCtl JACK Audio Connection Kit - Qt GUI Interface](http://qjackctl.sourceforge.net/):

[image: Main window]
[image: Audio (JACK) connections window]
[image: MIDI (ALSA) connections window]
[image: Patchbay definition profile editor window]

#### Enjoy!

Comment: Despite your efforts I wasn't able to figure it out yet. But I think you placed me on the correct track :D. +50.

Comment: Good sound, thank you, Thomas15v!

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out how to do this, in part because my system already has some of the unusual equipment needed.  You see, for under $10 typically you can buy a usb audio adapter you can plug your system speakers into and tell your computer to default to using that one for system sound.  On my Ubuntu system, my ubuntu skype, seems to prefer the on-board audio, which works out well because the usb sound device does not have a microphone jack anyway.

Just to be complete I located such [a sound adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00H6YTX06) online which purports to support Linux.  I can't say I'm recommending this one, necessarily, as I've never tried it.  At $3 and free shipping it might not be the greatest quality, but the one I'm using barely cost more than that, it has lasted me five years, and it sounds great, so you never can tell.  Oh and this one even has a microphone jack which mine does not.